# ~/.git on OSX weighing more than 27GB

Tags: macos, git

I work on Macbook Air, 128GB. After a month of usage, it began reporting disk being full quite often. As I ran omnidisksweeper to check for potential data hogs I have found that ~/.git folder takes 27.4 GB of the precious disk space. I tried to check what sort of data it is, but any git operation on the folder returns

```
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

I ran git gc --aggressive --prune, deleted more than 250 duplicates, but this has not affected the disk space usage, not in the slightest. I have only one git (1.8.5.2) installed at /usr/bin/git. Is there a way to compress/delete it without ravishing the whole system?
Please advise.

Comment: Then you have a lot of big changing objects in your GIT repo ;) you should think about your structure and what you can check in.

Comment: But that's not really true - I just use it for a couple of small to medium sized rails apps, nothing fancy. Can I just delete all but the last 5 changesets?

Comment: deleting everything but the last 5 changesets is not in the versionning philosophy (as you will delete your work :)). You should find a solution to the base problem, not just deleting some content. Moreover, if you delete your content now, you will have to do it again in some months :)

Comment: Are you putting your entire home directory under version control?!

Comment: Well, not personally, but some mysterious app most certainly did. I git pruned the whole folder, and considering all those heavy objects were inaccessible they were removed. Everything works (for now), and I pray to all known gods it won't have severe repercussions. Fingers crossed. On the upside - now I have loads of space for gifs with kittens. Topic closed.